# two-way binding on array does not work

Tags: ember.js

I have an array of strings that I render as a list of inputs.
Then there is a way to add a new item (new input) into this list.

However when change a text in the inputs and then add a new item, all the changes that were previously made to the old inputs are gone - and also the array of strings in my controller does not change.

Here is a code:
http://ember-twiddle.com/653be725890f234931dd

how can I preserve changes that are made to the "old inputs"?
I am quite suprised by this behaviour, since in angular this is a pretty common thing to do and it works out of the box... so I guess I must be doing something terribly wrong here :(

Comment: Your code works for me http://c2n.me/3mbbWAx

Comment: add a new field, then edit it and add a new one - the edited field will reset back to original; anyway, I found a solution (or workaround?) when array contains objects not primitives, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a way that solved the problem, but maybe there's a better way, but it can create a function to perform the change in the value index and the report that there was a change in the controller, sorry the English Google translation.

```
Template:
    {{#each valueList key="@index" as |value index|}}
      <div>{{input value=value change=(action 'updateItem' index)}}</div>
    {{/each}}

Controller:
    actions : {
        updateItem : function( index ) {
            this.get( 'valueList' )[ index ] = event.target.value;
            this.notifyPropertyChange( 'valueList' );
        },
     },
```

Comment: thanks it works (even though it seems like a nasty hack with the "notifyPropertyChange")